# ServerName issue, either www or http, can't have both.. Why?

Tags: apache2, .htaccess, www

So everything is set up right at my dnsprovider. I have both my subdomain and my main domain directed to my ip. However I can't seem to get my subdomain to work with both with and without www.

If in my Apache2 configfile I use `ServerName www.my.server.com` then it works as www.my.server.com but not as http://my.server.com..

If I rename the server `ServerName my.server.com` it works the other way around. without the www that is..

However I want both www and not www to point to my subdomain. 
How is this achieved? Been looking all over the place for this info without result. Thanks!

Comment: This is because `blah` and `www.blah` are 2 totally different hostnames.  You need an alias, like @LilloX beat me to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use "ServerAlias" directive, so:

```
ServerName www.my.server.com
ServerAlias my.server.com
```

Comment: Can't believe a simple command like ServerAlias was so hard to find. Google failed me on this one but you came through. Thanks so much!